# Sublime toggle comment is grayed out

Tags: comments, sublimetext

For sublime text 3059:
 - 'edit -> Comment -> toggle comment' is grayed out and I cannot comment out code.

Note, this is not the same issue as in:
[Keyboard shortcut to comment lines in Sublime Text 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17742781/keyboard-shortcut-to-comment-lines-in-sublime-text-3)

I have observed that when I enable logging:

```
sublime.log_commands(True)
```

ctrl+/ sends the correct command:

```
command: toggle_comment {"block": false}
```

But nothing happens.
This is something that only started happening today (I updated my system yesterday).

OS:
 - Linux Fedora 21
 - tried with standard us keyboard layout, I do not think it is due to keyboard layout as command is triggered.

Note:
- I'm now observing that a lot of other stuff doesn't work either. E.g ctrl+bs doesn't erase whole words anymore. But this sort of thing works well in other apps like eclipse...

Comment: first, try updating to [the latest build](http://www.sublimetext.com/3).

Answer (score 1):

I updated to latest 3065 but that did not fix.

It looks like my configuration must have broken something.

i.e:
I ran it as 'sudo subl' and I had restored the functionality.

I then moved the config file 
mv ~/.conf/sublime-text-3 ~/.conf/sublime-text-3_OLD

and then my functionality was restored again under regular user.

I think I will just re-configure it again.