# Sublime 3 toggle comment command doesn't work in Windows

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext3, preferences

I've edited the file *Preferences > Key Bindings User*, and added this:

```
[
  { "keys": ["ctrl+/"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": false } },
  { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+/"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": true } }, 
]
```

But the shortcuts doesn't work. What went wrong?

Comment: How do I get it to work?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I solved my problem:

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+keypad_divide"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": false } },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+keypad_divide"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": true } },   
]
```

Just replace '/' by 'keypad_divide'

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: I added these on the right panel of the keymap and save it. But still not working.

Answer (score 16):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17750124/3763649) works for me, with a QWERTY (Italian) keyboard, where the `/` is above the number `7`.

Add in *Preferences > Key Bindings User*

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+7"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": false } },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+7"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": true } }
```

It should works good on [German QWERTZ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25184101/3763649) keyboard also.

Comment: Works for me on a QWERTZ keyboard.

Comment: Works for me too.

Comment: The same on Linux

Comment: Works fine on german QWERTZ

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me on Windows 10:

```
{ "keys": ["control+keypad_divide"],"command": "toggle_comment", "args": {"block": false} }, 
{ "keys": ["shift+control+keypad_divide"],"command": "toggle_comment", "args": {"block": true}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, but what worked for me was

`ctrl + ç`

without going to preferences.

(I have no idea why, notice is the c cedilla)

Answer (score 1):

With portuguese keyboard layout (my case) I had to use this:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+7"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": false } },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+7"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": true } }
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution for italian keyboards also works for spanish keyboards on Windows 10:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+7"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": false } },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+7"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": true } }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+keypad_divide"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": false } },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+keypad_divide"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": true } },   
]
```

This worked for me thanks.... :)

Answer (score 0):

Follows this link for the solution:
[Keyboard shorcut to Toggle (Block) comment in Sublime-Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17742781/keyboard-shortcut-to-comment-lines-in-sublime-text-3)

Few additional comments:

1. Also, as a good practice try to edit the Default (Windows).sublime-keymap -User file to place your personal preferences
2. If the symbol still doesn't works for you, possibly due to different keyboard layout, then can change opt for other key as well for e.g.

> "keys": ["ctrl+shift+#"] ...

in the Default (Windows).sublime-keymap -User file.

Answer (score 0):

This one work for me under window 10

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+'"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": false } },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+'"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": true } }
```

Answer (score -2):

*[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+keypad_divide"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": false } },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+keypad_divide"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": true } },
]*

keypad_divide just solve my problem

Answer (score -2):

This has solved the issue for me, without having to add an alternate keyboard shortcut:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+'"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": false } },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+'"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": true } }
```

I don't quite understand why. This key undoubtedly types a slash(`/`) but SublimeText interprets it as an apostrophe(`'`) in the key binding.