# How to comment a block of code using a German keyboard

Tags: sublimetext3

I am using Sublime Text 3 to comment a block of code but I have a German keyboard.

I  already tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> but it does not work as mentioned in the Edit -> Comment menu.

Does anyone have a suggestion how to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keyboard shortcut to comment lines in Sublime Text 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17742781/keyboard-shortcut-to-comment-lines-in-sublime-text-3)

Comment: Short answer: in an alternate keyboard layout like German, this doesn't work because Sublime doesn't see the key that it expects when you press it. You need to modify the binding (which is outlined in the linked question above) to a different key. You can use `View > Show Console` and enter `sublime.log_input(True)` followed by pressing the key to see what Sublime sees it as (if anything) while making your binding.

Comment: @OdatNurd after follow as per your instructions i get this answer  focus_group {"group": 6} by pressing ctrl+/. By pressing shift+ctrl+/ i got commad  chr evt: { (0x7b)

Comment: I am on a Mac. `super+shift+forward_slash` works for me for comment the line you are on. On Windows `super` probably has to be changed to `ctrl`.