# Can you add a comment beside a field in YAML?

Tags: yaml

I have the following YAML object:

```yaml
# profile fields
firstName: string
lastName: string
phoneNum: string  # optional
active: boolean
notes: string  # optional
role: string # admin | market | client
by: User_Id
```

Is it allowed to add comments beside the properties' names such as:

```yaml
notes: string # optional 
role: string # admin | market | client
```

I couldn't find a resource that mentions that, and I have no way to test this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inline commenting in YAML files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44583624/inline-commenting-in-yaml-files) (The question gives a link to the YAML spec for comments and asks if inline commenting is allowed. The answer says that it's correct and gives a way for you to check on your own if your YAML is valid.)

Comment: @GinoMempin, no. that question and answer are complicated, they're talking about a linter and python. my question is direct. and I don't know python anyway

Comment: When you ask "*is it allowed*", allowed by who? By the [YAML spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#66-comments)? By a linter? By a library/tool that parses YAML files? By a platform that reads and uses YAML files? By other developers? Also, please indicate on which OS or platform are you on, so that people can suggest you a way to "*test this*".

Comment: @GinoMempin, Hi Gino. as per the specification. and I'm on Linux :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's allowed by the [YAML spec](https://yaml.org/spec/), latest version 1.2.2: https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/.

The same examples that you posted appear on the spec's section on [**2.1 Collections**](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#21-collections):

> **Example 2.2 Mapping Scalars to Scalars (player statistics)**
>
> ```yaml
> hr:  65    # Home runs
> avg: 0.278 # Batting average
> rbi: 147   # Runs Batted In
> ```

The full comment specs has its own section, **[6.6 Comments](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#66-comments)**. The main rules are that it starts with a `#` and "*must be separated from other tokens by white space characters*". It can also span multiple lines.

```yaml
firstName: john  # comment line 1
                 # comment line 2
lastName: doe
```

As for knowing if it would work and

> I have no way to test this

You can use any of the popular YAML linters (based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72675838/add-comment-beside-a-field-in-yaml#comment128373832_72675838), see [What is "Linting"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503559/what-is-linting)). It can either be a command-line tool (like `yq`), a website (like [YAMLlint](http://www.yamllint.com/)), an integrated tool on where you would be using your YAML file (like Gitlab's [CI Lint Tool](https://docs.gitlab.cn/14.0/ee/ci/lint.html#validate-gitlab-ciyml-syntax-with-the-ci-lint-tool)), an extension on your IDE/editor, or some language-specific library (like [`ruamel.yaml`](https://pypi.org/project/ruamel.yaml/) for Python as demonstrated by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44583624/inline-commenting-in-yaml-files?noredirect=1&lq=1) on a related question).

On YAMLlint, it shows your YAML as valid, but it strips out the comments because it "*give you a nice clean UTF-8 version of it.*" (also, as the YAML spec says, "*Comments are a presentation detail*" only and "*must not be used to convey content information*". Processors should just ignore them). The image does show the payload to the site included the comments, and the site responded with 200/OK:

[image: YAMLlint]

I personally use the [`yq`](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) command line utility.

```
$ cat test.yaml
# profile fields
firstName: string
lastName: string
phoneNum: string  # optional
active: boolean
notes: string  # optional
role: string # admin | market | client
by: User_Id

$ yq '.role' test.yaml
string

$ cat invalid.yaml
key1: [value2]
key2: key3: key4: value3

$ yq '.key2' invalid.yaml
Error: bad file 'invalid.yaml': yaml: line 2: mapping values are not allowed in this context
```